Windows 7 not found
I have a computer with Windows 7 installed that worked perfectly
Some days ago, Windows stopped with a BSOD ( 0x0000007A ). I don't know the reason because I haven't added any new device or so for a long time, but this is not the most important now ...
The important thing is that when I restart the computer, now it doesn't found Windows and after some seconds shows something like: "Reboot and select proper boot device"
So, I restarted the computer again and press F12 showing these entries ( both were created by Windows installer when I first installed Windows ):

Windows Boot Manager ( PO: WDCxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx )
PO: WDCxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx

If I manually select 1), Windows starts correctly
The problem is that I must do that every time I restart the computer
So, looks like something got misconfigured at boot level
Any solution to fix this boot problem?

You use Windows 7 only or dual windows? And in UEFI or Legacy?

BSODs don't only happen after you install new hardware. It sounds like your hard drive may be failing. Have you looking into modifying your boot configuration? I believe you can view and modify these in MSCONFIG.

Mr.Key7 -> It is Windows 7 Professional only ( no dual boot ) and UEFI installation

Error 0x0000007, also known as KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR, means either
that system memory is failing or that the disk's file-system integrity
is compromised. The problem is then with either memory or disk (or both).
Backup your data immediately! then check the health of your
memory and disk. This apparently being a very old computer, it's quite
possible for its hardware to suffer some failure.

And consider using a SUPPORTED OS instead.
